# Limit to infinity rule for fractions?

Tags: limits, self-learning

I am reading a book and it says to solve limits to infinity with a fraction such as:

$$\frac{5X^2 + 8X - 3}{3X^2 + 2}$$

We divide the numerator and denominator by the highest power of X in the DENOMINATOR so in this case it is $X^2$.  I get this helps simplify the equation, but what is to prevent someone from dividing by a higher power like $X^3$?  All components would evaluate to 0.

Is there another rule for limits that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: You can, but you would get a $\frac00$ indeterminate form, and we don't want that, because we cannot tell the limit directly.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense now why we divided by highest order of denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can divide by $X^3$ but we obtain

$$\frac{5X^2 + 8X - 3}{3X^2 + 2}=\frac{\frac 5 X + \frac 8{X^2} - \frac 3{X^3}}{\frac 3X + \frac2{X^3}}$$

which is again an indeterminate form.

In general, to avoid that this happens, the standard way is to factor out the dominating term from the numearator and the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The most dominant term in num is $5x^2$ and the most dominant term in den is $3x^2$
when $x$ is very large. So the required limit is $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5x^2}{3x^2}=\frac{5}{3}.$$

Comment: This doesn't at all answer the OPs question....